# I can't redirect the HTTP domain to the HTTPS domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with my domain. I have a ruby on rails Heroku app and bought a domain from google domains. I can't get "http://www.myapp.com" to redirect to "https://www.myapp.com" I tried to forward the HTTP version from google to the HTTPS version from Heroku multiple times but the website just ends up not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your entire application to be served over `https` then you can set  `force_ssl` config

```
# config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # [..]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security,
  # and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

You can refer to [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-https-with-ruby-on-rails) article for more info.